# Возможно ли как-то сократить условие?

Tags: php

Возможно ли получить еще более сокращенную запись условия?

```
if ($quantity < 0) {
    $quantity = 0;
}
```

Comment: А что, это условие тормозит компьютер?

Comment: $quantity = $quantity < 0 ? 0: $quantity;

Answer (score 6):

Вот:

```
$quantity = max($quantity, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще с тернарным оператором вариант есть:

```
$quantity = ($quantity < 0) ? 0 : $quantity;
```

Comment: так вообще-то длиннее получается

Comment: @Ипатьев, кстати  - да, вы абсолютно правы. Собственно первое, что приходит в голову при сокращение if - тернарник.